# How to open a file in your preferred IDE using a hyperlink?

Tags: url, ide, hyperlink

I want to create some hyperlinks in our web based log files so I can open a file in the IDE just by clicking on the hyperlink.

At his moment the solution does have to work only on Windows but it has to work with your preferred editor for the specified file. Currently this has to work with IDEA and Eclipse.

One issue is that the file PATH from the log (server) could be different than the one on the client so this could require some sort of re-mapping at client level.

I am fully aware that this may impose some security issue but I don't care and I can install, configure anything on the client computers in order to make the URI to work.

The solution has to work with Internet Explorer and Chrome.

One of the first questions is how to specify the action, because the action would be "edit" not "open".

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to create a universal solution for this. However, if you change the content type of the log files to something personal, for example, "myapp/logfile". You can learn your browser to open these types of resources with a specific application.

For example, for Firefox you can edit what actions to take on certain content types, for example, starting your IDE.

An solutions could be to create a JavaFX/Applet that opens your application.